# Get level-specific element counts from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, count, associative-array, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to determine the count of each array within a multidimensional associative array. For example, if I have an array like:

```
array(
    'food' => array(
        'soup' => array(
            'chicken noodle' => 
            'tomato' => 
            'french onion' => 
        ),

        'salad' => array(
            'house' => 
            'ceasar' =>
        ),
    ),
    'drink' => array(
        'soda' => array(
            'coke' => 
            'sprite' => 
            'dr pepper' => 
        ),

        'alcoholic' => array(
            'whiskey' => array(
                'Jim Beam' => 
                'Jameson' =>
                'Bushmills' =>
            ),
            'vodka' => array(
                'Stolichnaya' => 
                'Ketel One' =>
                'Grey Goose' =>
                'Belvedere' =>
            ),
            'rum' => array(
                'Captain Morgan' => 
                'Bacardi' =>
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Not too sure how to explain this so I'll do my best. I want to find out the count of each array inside the array. So the values I'd expect from this array would look something like:

```
array(
        // total count of all arrays at  "level 1" (i.e. food & drink)
        0 => 2,
        // total count of all arrays at  "level 2" (i.e. soup, salad, soda, alcoholic)
        1 => 4,
        // total count of all arrays at  "level 3" (i.e. chicken noodle, tomato, french onion, house, ceasar, coke, sprite, dr pepper, whiskey, vodka, rum)
        2 => 11,
        // total count of all arrays at  "level 4" (i.e. Jim Beam, Jameson, Bushmills, Stolichnaya, Ketel One, Grey Goose, Belvedere, Captain Morgan, Bacardi)
        3 => 9
)
```

Now I'm aware that I'm only using the index keys for the values as opposed to the values, and while it would be easier to get these values if the array was a standard indexed array (I think I'm using correct terminology here, feel free to correct me- the whole point of course is for me to understand here- not for someone to just "give me an answer" :)) since I could then just loop through the array in a `for($i = 0 $i < count($array); $i++)` loop and increment my counts accordingly. I've searched SO for such an issue but haven't found it, if I missed it though feel free to simply point me to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, use a recursive function (`countLevels` in the example below) that goes through every level of the array, counting each index that is an array, and adds that count to a master "counting" array (`$levels`). `$levels` is [passed by reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), and the count of each level is updated directly on it. You can stick this right into your class, as I did below.

Below is what I think you want your class to look like. If you want `$data` to be a member of the class, declare the variable with `var $data` and fill it inside the [constructor](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
class Test {
    public function getCounts($data) {
        $counts = array();
        $this->countLevels($counts, 0, $data);
        return $counts;
    }

    // Counts the number of arrays in each level of $data
    private function countLevels(&$levels, $current, $parent) {
        if (! isset($levels[$current])) {
            $levels[$current] = 0;
        }
        foreach ($parent as $child) {
            $levels[$current]++;
            if (is_array($child)) {
                $this->countLevels($levels, $current+1, $child);
            }
        }
        return $levels;
    }
}

// Let's use the class! Create an instance of it
$test = new Test();

// Fill the data array
$data = [
    'food' => [
        'soup' => [
            'chicken_noodle' => '',
            'tomato' => '',
            'french onion' => '',
        ],
        'salad' => [
            'house' => '',
            'ceasar' => '',
        ],
    ],
    'drink' => [
        'soda' => [
            'coke' => '',
            'sprite' => '',
            'dr pepper' => '',
        ],
        'alcoholic' => [
            'whiskey' => [
                'Jim Beam' => '',
                'Jameson' => '',
                'Bushmills' => '',
            ],
            'vodka' => [
                'Stolichnaya' => '',
                'Ketel One' => '',
                'Grey Goose' => '',
                'Belvedere' => '',
            ],
            'rum' => [
                'Captain Morgan' => '',
                'Bacardi' => '',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

// Count the data for arrays on each level
$counts = $test->getCounts($data);

// Print the results
var_export($counts);
```

Output:

> ```
> array (
>   0 => 2,
>   1 => 4,
>   2 => 11,
>   3 => 9,
> )
> ```

Comment: That will only display the count of the first index not each of them. So that would only return:Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)

Comment: I feel like there has to be some sort of recursion that goes on to accomplish this. I'm just not sure how to do that. :/

Comment: In your initial question, your example "result" array showed that you wanted the number of indices in the _first_ arrays, not digging any deeper. Do you want your answer to be like: Array([0] => array([0] => 5, [1] => 19), [1] => 3)?

Comment: I thought I showed exactly what I wanted it to look like. :P I've edited the post to describe the result array to try and better explain what I'm getting at.

Comment: Updated! This should be what you're looking for?

Comment: Still not quite there. I'm getting an undefined offset notice on the $levels[$current]++; line and your function isn't actually returning anything. I'm assuming levels should be. Either way the numbers aren't right. Not sure if scope is a concern or what the issue is, but I **am** writing this as a method in a class so I've created a test case for this situation. I'll update your answer with what I've got so far.

Comment: Grr... it looks like my edit won't be visible to anyone but me until my edit is "peer reviewed". Not sure if that means **you** are the peer or not. And when I tried to remove my edit and put my edit in my original post (which is what I think I should've done initially-- still learning how to use SO) it wouldn't let me remove it so I'm editing my original post now so it's visible by everyone.

Comment: Updated again! This should do it for you, unless you want $data inside the class.

Comment: So close, but you're returning $counts instead on $count in your example (simple typo) and the move of the $levels[$current]++ turns out was wrong. If you want to update your answer to be correct (please try running it to ensure it works-- www.ideone.com) I'll then check off your answer for the cred. :) Thanks again for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Derp, what is with me misreading? I thought you wanted to _count the arrays_, not all elements in the arrays, thus the movement of `$levels[$current]++`. My apologies. No worries! Same to you, thanks for the patience. :P